# How to define shortcut-keys for executing certain applications?

Tags: shortcut-keys, mint

How can I define shortcut-keys for executing certain applications? Like opening `Terminal` when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> or opening `gedit` when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this, go to System setting - Keybowrd -Shortcut -custom and click on "+" add and then put any desired name like for example `gedit` and command `gedit` and click apply  as shown in screenshort below-

[image: Explaing shortcut key for gedit]

after that there will a "disable" ,click on it and it will chang to "new accelrator" then just press the key you want like press Ctrl+G to assign thats it.